# Spark rest url job submission in java

Tags: rest, apache-spark, livy

i am new to spark and would like to do rest url submission on a local machine, i was able to do a rest submission on a remote cluster.but everytime submitting it to remote cluster is a bit tedious , is there anyway i can submit the jar to spark rest url on a local machine for functional testing.

anything like http://localhost:4040/v1/submissions/create

I am using http://localhost:4040/v1/submissions/create
 however this doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Apache Livy service is available to submit spark jobs through REST. Please follow below livy examples to know about how to submit jobs through REST call.

https://livy.incubator.apache.org/examples/

Thanks
Ravi